# how to place CURL in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How to insert php curl function in WordPress. I have tried this PHP code and it is working as expected. How to convert same curl function in WordPress.

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.bstcm.no/customer/-8/offers");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
$username = 'atrium',
$password = '3HnzkG2p',
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password)
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$details = json_decode($response, TRUE);
?>
```

I tried this:

```
<?php 
$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://api.bstcm.no/customer/-8/offers', array(

    'headers' => array(),
    'body' => array('username' =>'atrium','password' => '3HnzkG2p')
    )
);

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
   echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
   echo 'response:<pre>';
   print_r( $response );
   echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Authentication requires either the username and password be passed in the URL (no longer reccomended) or to be Base64 encoded in the "Authorization" header starting with "Basic " and a colon (:) separating the the username and password:

```
<?php
$response = wp_remote_get( 'http://api.bstcm.no/customer/-8/offers', array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( 'atrium:3HnzkG2p' )
    )
);

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
   $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
   echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
   echo 'response:<pre>';
   print_r( $response );
   echo '</pre>';
}
?>
```